# Cannot start windows phone emulator in visual studio 2015

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015

My machine is HP EliteBook 8540w which supports Hyper-V as far as I know and I have enabled it in BIOS. However, I am receiving the following error when trying to start emulator for Windows Phone apps in Visual Studio 2015:

> Windows Phone Emulator is unable to start because the hypervisor is not running.

The more detailed screen shot follows:
[image]

According to my [i7-720QmCPU specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/43122/Intel-Core-i7-720QM-Processor-6M-Cache-1_60-GHz), it supports VT-d
[image: Credit: Intel]

So what is the reason for it being unable to start the emulator on my machine?

Update:
I also checked using the BIOS settings using coreinfo tool with the results as in the following picture:

[image]

Update:

Following [stijnvangaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5427709/stijnvangaal)'s comment, I ran the following command as administrator and rebooted.

> 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto'

But, in the wake of next run I faced the following Window ("Virtual machine service not running")

[image]

Then, I started this (by clicking the link on the message box):

[image]

Under, action menu, I clicked "start service" and then ran the application again in visual studio. Success? Not yet unfortunately, ending up in this (feeling desperate):

[image]

Comment: Try this in administrative command prompt 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto'. then reboot

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue :
1 - I disable the Hyper V mode in the Windows Feature :

- Go to ‘Programs and Features’.
- Select Turn Windows Features on or off.
- Deselect Hyper-V and click OK.

2 - Restart the computer

3 - Enable Hyper V again in the Windows Feature.

And it works !
Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just disable Hyper-V on "Programs and Features" (if it is enabled). Then restart computer and turn it on again. Problem solved for me